# Docker and Python

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I want to write a program in Python which starts a docker, executes some commands inside the docker and returns the output. This is, something I would do in a shell like :

```
docker run --rm -i -it name_docker_image 

echo "Input for programm" | script.sh
```

Output of the script

I am trying to do it with a code like:

```
    process = subprocess.Popen("sudo docker run --rm -i -it syntaxnet",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    process.communicate("echo \""+ sentence + "\" | work/demo.sh")                               

    out = process.stdout.read()
    retyurned_value= out.splitlines()
```

But it gives me an error message: "the input device is not a TTY". How can I fix it?

Comment: I would recommend using an API client, e.g. https://github.com/docker/docker-py over trying to use subprocess.

Comment: How do you run the code? And BTW the `-i` is redundant.

Comment: remove -t from the options. Actually, you can remove -i as well since all you're interested in is the output of the script